# Call base method as base type

Tags: c#

I have these 2 classes:

```
public class A
{
    public void ShowType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetType().ToString());
    }
}

public class B : A
{

}
```

and this main code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    B b = new B();

    b.ShowType();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Right now, the output is "*type of* B". Is there any way to call the ShowType() method from a B instance as an A instance? So that the output would be "*type of* A"?

Thanks.

Comment: is this you homework?

Comment: No, it's a simplified code for an issue I've encountered at work. We have a third party class that we want to inherit from, but when we call a base method, some reflection happens, and it complains that it doesn't recognize the new derived type.

Comment: Can't you just make an instance of the base class?

Comment: What does the third party say about inheritance from this class? It sounds like they don't expect you to do so, if inheriting from it breaks functionality... Can you [wrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) the class instead?

Comment: This was the first thing I did. It worked, of course. But I had a lot of properties from the wrapped class that were just duplicated, so I tried inheritance and encountered this issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to opt out if polymorphism here, you can simply use `typeof(A).ToString()`:

```
public class A
{
    // Will always output "type of A"
    public void ShowType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(A).ToString());
    }
}
```

If you can't change the code of `A` you only have the possibility to override `ShowType`. However, for this to work, it needs to be `virtual`.

However, based on your comment to the question you don't actually want `ShowType` to output `"type of A"`. You want `GetType()` to return `typeof(A)` no matter what the actual type of the instance is.
You are out of luck there, **this is not possible.**

You might want to think about favoring composition over inheritance here and don't derive from that base class but instead make your class use an instance of that base class.

Comment: I don't want to just write the base type, I want to call a base method as the base instance. This is the question. The method in the example just writes the type to demonstrate that it's called as the derived type.

Comment: @ViorelMoisei: Please provide a real world example. Your sentence *"I want to call a base method as the base instance"* makes no sense, really :)

Comment: As I commented above,  it's a simplified code for an issue I've encountered at work. We have a third party class that we want to inherit from (this would be "A" from my example), but when we call a base method from the derived class ("B" from my example), some reflection happens, and it complains that it doesn't recognize the new derived type. So I would like to be able to call a method of the base third party class ("A") as that base class ("A"), so when they do their reflection, they can see that it's their type ("A), not mine ("B").

Comment: @ViorelMoisei: I think the 3rd party have to change their component, if they support inheritance of the classes. Otherwise you have no chance to get it work.

Comment: @ViorelMoisei: As I said, that is impossible. You only have one instance. And that instance is of your type and not the base type. No amount of casting or other stuff will change that fact. Your instance will always be of your type.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't mean something like declare `ShowType` virual and override it, basically, no. `GetType()` is non-virtual and always returns the actual runtime type of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().BaseType.ToString());
```

Of course, this will return `System.Object` when `b` is an `A` class instance.

Comment: I don't want to just write the base type, I want to call a base method as the base instance. This is the question. The method in the example just writes the type to demonstrate that it's called as the derived type.

Answer (score 0):

this is your condition

First, you don't want to fix your base code.
second, you call ShowType() through B instance.
so, this is my answer

this is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

  B b = new B();
  Type aType = b.Gettype().BaseType; //this is that get A through B class
  ((a)Activator.CreateInstance(atype)).ShowType(); //call ShowType of A class

}
```